# hide/show label in input and textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, label, show-hide

I am trying to get a input and textarea label hide/show function to work, but my Jquery skills are not good enough..:/

You probably seen this a thousand times, and I have read page up and down about it, but still I havent been able to figure it out.

The first part of the code works fine, it changes the text to a lighter color when the element gets focus, and disappears when you start to type. It is probably not very well written, but it is to the best of my abilitys right now.

```
$("input, #email_text").focusin(function(){

$("label.input", this).css("color", "#f3f3f3");

});

$("input, #email_text").keypress(function(){

$("label.input", this).fadeOut("normal");

});
```

Here I want the script to do the following: If the element loose focus, I want the labeltext to fade back in, exept if the user have written something in the field. I probably have the if/else statement screwed up, and I have not yet got a grip on the .val function.

```
$("input, #email_text").focusout(function() {

if($("#email_text").val() !="") {

$("label.input", this).fadeIn("normal").css("color", "#f3f3f3");

}} else { 

("label.input", this).hide();

});
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this? I`m kind of giving up on this, and should probably have started with something more basic.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Vegar Vallestad

Edit:

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="email_text">
<label class="input">Please leave a message..</label>
<textarea name="message" id="email_text"><?php echo "</tex" . "tarea>"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post html? Oh and you have a couple errors `}} else {` should be `} else {` and then `});` should be `}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input, #email_text").on({
    focus: function() {
        $("label.input", this).css("color", "#f3f3f3");
    },
    keyup: function() {
        $("label.input", this).fadeOut();
    },
    blur: function() {
        if($("#email_text").val() !="") {
            $("label.input", this).css("color", "#f3f3f3").fadeIn();
        } else { 
            $("label.input", this).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replies, I have added the html to the original question.

When I try your answer adeneo, I get a javascript error with this message: $("input, #email_text").on is not a function

Comment: I have read up on "$ is not a function", and from what I understand this is common? if you use more than one library on a site. But the only library I use is jQuery, so I dont understand why this error occurs. Unless it has something to do with php?

Comment: I figured it out in the jQuery forum, I was using the 1.6 version, when I should have been using the 1.7 version, the .on function is just recently added and not covered by the 1.6 version of the script.